# Setting ShaderMaterial `skinning` property to `true` causes 'too many uniforms' error

Tags: three.js, glsl

I have the following function which loads a mesh from a JSON file:

```
loadJSONModel(filename, modelName) {
let loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load(`assets/${filename}`, (geometry, materials) => {

  let material = Shader.createShaderMaterial(Shader.LINEAR_BLEND_SKINNING_VERT, Shader.BASIC_FRAG);
  let mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.material.skinning = true;
  mesh.rotation.x = 0.5 * Math.PI;
  mesh.rotation.z = 0.7 * Math.PI;
  this.scene.add(mesh);

});
```

where the `Shader.createShaderMaterial` function does the following:

```
 static createShaderMaterial(vertex, fragment, uniforms) {
    if (uniforms === undefined) uniforms = {};
    return new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: uniforms,
      vertexShader: vertex,
      fragmentShader: fragment,
    });
  }
```

And now I keep getting this dastardly error:

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders ERROR: too many uniforms
```

which goes away if I don't do `mesh.material.skinning = true`, but of course, I need the skinning flag to be set in the shader, so I need that there.

My problem doesn't seem to be the same as others I've found thus far through Google. I'm not reusing my geometry from another mesh. I'm constructing a SkinnedMesh too, not any old mesh. My setup can support 1024 uniforms. I'm baffled. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it had to be something stupid like the fact that the ThreeJS WebGLProgram was setting the `MAX_BONES` macro in my shader file to 1024, and I was using that value in my shader to initialize this uniform: `uniform mat4 boneMatrices[MAX_BONES]`, and my system only supported 1024 uniforms max.

Now the question is why the `allocateBones` function of `THREE.WebGLPrograms` does this:

```
function allocateBones( object ) {

        if ( capabilities.floatVertexTextures && object && object.skeleton && object.skeleton.useVertexTexture ) {

            return 1024;

        } else {

            // default for when object is not specified
            // ( for example when prebuilding shader to be used with multiple objects )
            //
            //  - leave some extra space for other uniforms
            //  - limit here is ANGLE's 254 max uniform vectors
            //    (up to 54 should be safe)

            var nVertexUniforms = capabilities.maxVertexUniforms;
            var nVertexMatrices = Math.floor( ( nVertexUniforms - 20 ) / 4 );

            var maxBones = nVertexMatrices;

            if ( object !== undefined && (object && object.isSkinnedMesh) ) {

                maxBones = Math.min( object.skeleton.bones.length, maxBones );

                if ( maxBones < object.skeleton.bones.length ) {

                    console.warn( 'WebGLRenderer: too many bones - ' + object.skeleton.bones.length + ', this GPU supports just ' + maxBones + ' (try OpenGL instead of ANGLE)' );

                }

            }

            return maxBones;

        }

    }
```

ie. why does satisfying `capabilities.floatVertexTextures && object && object.skeleton && object.skeleton.useVertexTexture` entail that `MAX_BONES` is automatically 1024. But that is another question, and one which I am not particularly concerned about at this point. So I've decided to just use a `RawShaderMaterial` and manually set my `MAX_BONES` macro to an appropriate value.

Comment: That sounds like a bug ... three.js uses floating point textures for bones if it can. If it can't then it uses uniforms. It uses floating point textures because there aren't enough uniforms. In your case it looks like there's a bug because in the code you highlight, it thinks it can use floating point textures but then it fails to actually use them and instead allocates too many uniforms.

Comment: I've recently refactored all this a little bit. Do you mind checking the `dev` branch and see if this is still an issue?

Comment: It is no longer an issue. (v103)